# What is the simplest way to convert a Dataset object to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, orm, sqlalchemy, dataset

The Python [Dataset module](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) is based on Sqlalchemy and exposes a function to return all records in a table called all(). all() returns an iterable Dataset object.

```
users = db['user'].all()

for user in db['user']:
   print(user['age'])
```

**What is the simplest way to convert a Dataset object to a Pandas DataFrame object?**

For clarity, I am interested in utilizing Dataset's functionality as it has already loaded the table into a Dataset object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
import dataset
import pandas
db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///db.sqlite3')
data = list(db['my_table'].all())
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Comment: I’ll check this out and report back.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=db['user'])
df
```

similarly

```
pd.DataFrame(db['user'])
```

should do the same thing

You can also specify the columns or index:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Does this solution use the Dataset module per the question? I don’t see an import for dataset.

Answer (score 0):

After some significant time invested into [Dataset module](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), I found that the all() could be iterated into a list and then turned into a pandas dataframe. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
import dataset
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
names = ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Ricky']
ages = [31, 30, 31, 30]
df['names'] = names
df['ages'] = ages

print(df)

# create a dict oriented as records from dataframe
user = df.to_dict(orient='records')

# using dataset module instantiate database
db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///mydatabase.db')

# create a reference to a table
table = db['user']

# insert the complete dict into database
table.insert_many(user)

# use Dataset .all() to retrieve all table's rows
from_sql = table.all()  # custom ResultIter type (iterable)

# iterate ResultIter type into a list
data = []
for row in from_sql:
    data.append(row)

# create dataframe from list and ordereddict keys
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=from_sql.keys)

# this does not drop the id column, but it should??
df_new.drop(columns=['id'])

print(df_new)
```

---

```
'''
   names  ages
0    Bob    31
1   Jane    30
2  Alice    31
3  Ricky    30

      id  names  ages
0      1    Bob    31
1      2   Jane    30
2      3  Alice    31
3      4  Ricky    30

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created some helper functions that should make this process even simpler:

```
import dataset
import pandas as pd

def df_dataset_save(df, table_name, db_name='db'):
    try:
        df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
        db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///' + db_name + '.sqlite')
        table = db[table_name]
        table.insert_many(df)
        return 'success'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None


def df_dataset_query_all(table_name, db_name='db', ids=False):
    try:
        db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///' + db_name + '.sqlite')
        table = db[table_name]
        from_sql = table.all()
        data = []
        for row in from_sql:
            data.append(row)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=from_sql.keys)
        if not ids:
            df.drop('id', axis=1, inplace=True)
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None


# create dataframe
users = pd.DataFrame()
names = ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Ricky']
ages = [31, 30, 31, 30]
users['names'] = names
users['ages'] = ages

# save dataframe
df_dataset_save(users, 'users')

# query saved dataframe
new_user = df_dataset_query_all('users')

print(new_user)

'''
    names  ages
0     Bob    31
1    Jane    30
2   Alice    31
3   Ricky    30
'''
```